# dojo function does not working in a tag

Tags: javascript, dojo

hi i am studying dojo based node.js When i perform a ajax created a table to a string.

and I have one row in the table that insert a link.In order to call a function.

But when I click on a link does not work function.

error message->Uncaught ReferenceError: func is not defined.

plz help me..

my board.html

```
   require([ "dojo/parser","dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/request", "dojo/json","dojo/_base/array"
          ,"dijit/Dialog","dijit/form/Button","dijit/form/CheckBox","dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
        "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dojo/domReady!" ], function(parser,dom,on,request,json,arrayUtil,Dialog,Button,CheckBox) {
    parser.parse();
    .....
    function func(no){
       alert('seq:'+no);
    }
    var xhrArgs = {
                url: '/getData',
                handleAs: "json",
                load: function(data){
                     var output ='';
                        output+='<table  class="output" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">';
                        output+='<thead>';
                        output+='<tr><th>NO</th><th>NAME</th><th>FORM</th><th>DESCRIPTION</th><th>WRITER</th>';
                        output+='</tr>';
                        output+='</thead>';
                        output+='<tbody>';
                      arrayUtil.forEach(data,function(item,i){
                            output+='<tr>';
                            output+='<td>'+item.seq+'</td>';
                            output+='<td>'+item.name+'</td>';
                            output+='<td><a href="#" onclick="func('+item.seq+');return false;">'+item.form+'</a></td>';
                            output+='<td>'+item.desc+'</td>';
                            output+='<td>'+item.writer+'</td>';
                            output+='</tr>';
                      });//end for
                      output+='</tbody>';
                      output+='</table>';
                      resultDiv.innerHTML = output; 
               },//end load
             ......
```

Comment: Have you tried to call the function with dojo-data-props? Like
    output+='<td><a href="#" dojo-data-probs="onClick:func('+item.seq+');return false;">'+item.form+'</a></td>'; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `func()` function is locally scoped in the `require()` callback function. This means that you cannot see it, unless you're calling the function from inside the `require()` callback.

However, an onclick attribute can only access the global scope, so in your current situation it can not execute `func()`, that's why it's giving the error that it's not defined.

To solve this, you can do two things:

1. Move your `func()` to global scope
2. Move your event handling to the local `require()` scope

---

### Move your `func()` to global scope

To move your function to the global scope, you should rewrite your function as:

```
func = function(no){
   alert('seq:'+no);
}
```

Because there is no `var` in front of it, it's actually being applied to the global scope. You could also write the following:

```
window.func = function(no){
    alert('seq:'+no);
}
```

This is the easiest solution, but also the most ugly one. Usually it's recommended to use the global scope as less as possible, and in this case it's not really necessary.

### Move your event handling to the local `require()` scope

A better solution (I think) is to move your event handling into the same local scope as your function is in. However, in order to do that, you cannot use the same strategy you're using now. You will have to replace your `output` DOM string by constructing proper DOM nodes using the **dojo/dom-construct** module.

For example:

```
var table = domConstruct.create('table', {
    class: "output",
    cellspacing: 0,
    cellpadding: 0,
    border: 1
});
domConstruct.place('<thead>' +
    '<tr><th>NO</th><th>NAME</th><th>FORM</th><th>DESCRIPTION</th><th>WRITER</th>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</thead>', table);
var body = domConstruct.create("tbody");
arrayUtil.forEach(data, function(item,i){
    var row = domConstruct.create("tr");
    domConstruct.place('<td>'+item.seq+'</td>', row);
    domConstruct.place('<td>'+item.name+'</td>', row);
    var cell = domConstruct.create('td');
    domConstruct.place(cell, row);
    var link = domConstruct.create("a", {
        href: "#",
        innerHTML: item.form
    });
    on(link, "click", function() {
        func(item.seq);
        return false;
    });
    domConstruct.place(link, cell);
    domConstruct.place('<td>'+item.desc+'</td>', row);
    domConstruct.place('<td>'+item.writer+'</td>', row);
    domConstruct.place(row, body);
});
domConstruct.place(body, table);
domConstruct.place(table, resultDiv);
```

This piece of code replaces your entire DOM construction. It creates DOM nodes and uses the **dojo/on** module to add the `func` function as event handler for the **onClick** event.

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D8k96/2/) that demonstrates this solution.

This has several benefits:

- Your `func()` is only available where it has to be available. Nobody can override it by using a variable with the same name in the global scope.
- You can see I'm using less HTML code in the JavaScript part and I have less JavaScript functions in the HTML part (the `onclick` attribute is no longer necessary). If you improve this even further you can decouple the HTML code and the JavaScript code, improving the structure of your application.